# Detecting if a string is just made up of spaces?

Tags: c, string

What's the most efficient/safest way to check if a string in C is made up only of spaces? Do I need to write a function myself to check or is there one in string.h that I can use?

Comment: beware of the `is`\* functions: they **require** their argument be converted to `unsigned char`. See 7.4/1 in [the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, writing your own is trivial:

```
int IsSpaces( char * s ) {

    while ( * s ) {
        if ( ! isspace( * s ) ) {
            return 0;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Anything you use from the standard library is not likely to be much more efficient.

Comment: No offense unapersson, but I find your coding style very hard to read.

Comment: @night Sorry about that, it has actually been developed over years of teaching people C and C++ to be as clear as I can make it.

Comment: The only part that seems hard to read to me is the space around the contents of parentheses. I'm not sure how that makes it *easier* to read; it appears to be splitting up things that logically go together.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand that, but I respect it since I'm only 16 and coding style is very personal. But I will give some backup on what I find annoying: Too much spacing with brackets, inconsistent spacing between `while(` and `if (`, dereference operator spaced from the operand (you don't write - 5 either when you mean -5 right?), a newline after the opening function bracket and a single statement bracketed and indented (the `return 0;`). On the other hand, my coding style is very terse, which can be hard too read too.

Comment: cast the isspace argument to avoid UB: `isspace((unsigned char)*s)`.

Comment: Use `const`: `int IsSpaces(const char * s);`

Comment: @night You are right about the difference between while and if - it must be some weird personal tic I've never noticed before - it shall be corrected! If you want to see my style used in a real project take a look at the code for csvfix at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/, which I think is quite readable, though the app is semantically quite hacky.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if (!s[strspn(s, " ")]) /* it's all spaces */
```

If you want to also include tabs, newlines, etc. in your definition of "spaces", simply add them to the second argument of `strspn`.

Comment: Your line of code is nifty, very clever, and very hard to understand (esp. before I fixed your syntax error ;))

Comment: OK, more efficient than strspn() == strlen().  Might be worth a comment that you will index the trailing \0 byte IFF the span is the entire length, thus the ! '\0' will be true-ish.

Answer (score 1):

When you say space, do you mean exactly  or a spacing character?

However, there is no such function, this works though:

```
int isonlyspaces(char *str) {
    while (*str++ == ' ');
    return --str == '\0';
}
```

If you mean spacing characters instead of a literal space, this version is appropriate:

```
int isonlyspaces(char *str) {
    while (isspace(*str++));
    return --str == '\0';
}
```

Comment: cast the isspace argument to avoid UB: `isspace((unsigned char)*str++)`.

Comment: @pmg: AFAIK `isspace` is defined to take an int so there won't be any trouble.

Comment: Are you sure `char` is unsigned? ... `char *buf = "José Peña";`

Comment: Shouldn't last line be `return --str == '\0'`?

Answer (score 1):

`man string.h` brought me to the following manpage.

NAME
       strspn, strcspn - search a string for a set of characters

SYNOPSIS

```
   #include <string.h>

   size_t strspn(const char *s, const char *accept);

   size_t strcspn(const char *s, const char *reject);
```

DESCRIPTION

- The strspn() function calculates the
  length of the initial segment of s
  which consists entirely of characters
  in accept.
- The strcspn() function calculates the
  length of the initial segment of s
  which consists entirely of 
  characters  not  in       reject.